# When i need to update RC code to Android Q?

Tags: android, react-native

I do not work with code at all. But we have 1 app on android programmed with React Native (old version).

Some told me that when Android Q (or 10) is published we need to upgrade our source code to be able to "publish" new apps or new updates to the stores.

This is true? If this is true, before what date we need to update our code for posting new updates or versions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No.  As of August, the Google Play Store required your targetSDKVersion to be at least 26, and I'm sure in a year or so they'll up it to 27.  But nothing is needed just to support Android Q, unless your app is using a feature/API that got significantly changed.